# react-bootstrap-sweetalert how to disable submit button after first click?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with `react-bootstrap-sweetalert` library in react. Actually it works fine, untill slow internet connection. When someone tries to click submit button, because of the slow internet (I'm simulating it through "Network section [Slow 3G]") alert is not closing exactly at time after clicking a button, but after several seconds. So, there is probability that someone can click several times submit button. It is a problem, because several same requests can flow to backend and database. In other sections without using a library I can just "disable" react `states` after handling `onClick`.

So question is - to disable button in `react-bootstrap-sweetalert` library after handling `onConfirm` function.
Code:

```js
  handleSubmitInvoice = () => {
    this.setState({
      sweetalert: (
        <SweetAlert
          warning
          showCancel
          confirmBtnText={this.state.alert.label.sure}
          cancelBtnText={this.state.alert.label.cancel}
          confirmBtnBsStyle="success"
          cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
          disabled={disableButton}
          title={this.state.alert.label.areyousure}
          onConfirm={() => this.submit()}
          onCancel={() => this.hideAlert()}
        >
          {this.state.alert.confirmSubmit}
        </SweetAlert>
      )
    });
  };
```

in render():

```js
          <button
              className="btn btn-success btn-sm"
              onClick={this.handleSubmitInvoice}
           >   
              submit
          </button>
```

submit function:

```js
  submit = () => {
    const req = { invoice: this.state.invoiceNumber };
    Axios.post("/api", req)
      .then(() => {
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: "/mypathname",
          state: {
            fromSubmitInvoice: true
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        Alert.error(
          err.response.data.code === "internal_error"
            ? this.state.alert.raiseError
            : err.response.data.text,
          {
            position: "top-right",
            effect: "bouncyflip",
            timeout: 2000
          }
        );

        this.hideAlert();
      });
  };
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-alert-problem-ktzcb
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not able to disable your confirm button.Right ???

Comment: @PrakashKarena Yes. I am not able to disable `confirm` button after pressing it.

Comment: disabled={true } try this and see what happens. It disabled or not?

Comment: @PrakashKarena, `disabled={true}` makes button disabled. But, in my code I created `disableButton` state, which is false as default, and becomes true after `submit` function in `this.setState({disableButton: true}`, unfortunatelly it doesn't work and I don't know why. May be, because this is library it has to handle those states differently. I already created same Alert without using library, and it disables button after submitting perfectly. Just interesting is it possible to do the same using library.

Comment: i have to check your full code for that it is possible then add your code and let me know

Comment: @PrakashKarena, I simulated similar problem in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-alert-problem-ktzcb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved try this out

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SweetAlert from "react-bootstrap-sweetalert";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const SweetAlertFunction = ({ show, disableButton, submit, hideAlert }) => {
  return (
    <SweetAlert
      warning
      show={show}
      showCancel
      confirmBtnText="confirmBtnText"
      cancelBtnText="cancelBtnText"
      confirmBtnBsStyle="success"
      cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
      disabled={disableButton}
      title="title"
      onConfirm={submit}
      onCancel={hideAlert}
    >
      submit
    </SweetAlert>
  );
};

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      disableButton: false,
      show: false
    };
  }

  hideAlert() {
    this.setState({
      show: false
    });
  }

  submit() {
    this.setState({ disableButton: true });
    console.log("submit");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ disableButton: false });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    const { show, disableButton } = this.state;
    console.log("disableButton", disableButton);
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        <SweetAlertFunction
          show={show}
          disableButton={disableButton}
          submit={() => this.submit()}
          hideAlert={() => this.hideAlert()}
        />
        <button
          className="btn btn-success btn-sm"
          onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}
        >
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: live example https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-alert-problem-tziu3

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since you are assigning the `Sweetalert` component to the `sweetalert` state, you need to have a local state that controls the disabled state, but to make it simple, you can make `sweetalert` state control the visibility/presence of the `Sweetalert` component, like below:

```
handleSubmitInvoice() {
  // just set sweetalert to true to show the Sweetalert component
  this.setState({ sweetalert: true });
}

render() {
    const { sweetalert, disableButton } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        // this makes disableButton reactive and pass it automatically to Sweetalert component
        {sweetalert && (
          <SweetAlert
            warning
            showCancel
            confirmBtnText="confirmBtnText"
            cancelBtnText="cancelBtnText"
            confirmBtnBsStyle="success"
            cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
            disabled={disableButton}
            title="title"
            onConfirm={() => this.submit()}
            onCancel={() => this.hideAlert()}
          >
            submit
          </SweetAlert>
        )}
        <button
          className="btn btn-success btn-sm"
          onClick={this.handleSubmitInvoice}
        >
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You can see it in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-alert-problem-lv0l5

P.S.  I added `setTimeout` in submit to make disabling of button noticeable.